# Как исправить ошибку в реакте?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Почему выдает ошибку Unexpected token, expected "," ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это всё нужно положить в родительский элемент. Можно, например, использовать [фрагменты](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Comment: Cейчас можно просто <> </> обрамить, чтоб не писать React.Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такая ошибка из-за того, что выводить контент в компоненте нужно обязательно обернутым в один (!) родительский элемент.

```
return (
  <>
    {your content}
  </>
)
```

Так же это может быть тег div и т.д.